# PHP APC 5.3.8 Hangs Page Request

Tags: php, nginx, apc

I had difficulty finding the newest version of php_apc.dll so I went ahead and compiled it myself. I had no issue getting it compiled using NTS v5.3.8. I had two separate files set up to test, one with a simple `phpinfo()` call on it and the other being the standard `apc.php` file that comes with the apc source files.

Strangely, when I would load the `phpinfo()` file it would work totally fine, but when I tried to access `apc.php` the webserver would hang until a timeout. I restarted the webserver, accessed `apc.php` and it worked just fine, but trying to go back to `phpinfo()` would cause the server to hang until timeout. It is probably worth noting that phpmyadmin and my own codeigniter application do not work period, even after a restart.

I have tried previous versions of apc with no luck; 5.3.5 with apc.stat = 0 works but I am in need of that feature as this is a development server, but I'm testing out some production type caching.

Noteworthy stuff:
Server is powered by Nginx 1.0.8 running PHP 5.3.8 (using fast-cgi). Everything works as intended with the exception of when apc is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the php_apc.dll from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/
You can find there different versions of it.